# query XML while ignoring namespace?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I'm trying to query XML while ignoring namespaces, because the result set has multiple namespaces.  I've gotten to the DataSets node, but I can't figure out how to get out the multiple DataSourceName/CommandType/CommandText. Ideally I want:

```
DataSetName   DataSourceName   CommandType      CommandText
SQLDS         SQLDS            StoredProcedure  ReportProc_aaaaa
SQLDS         SQLDS            StoredProcedure  ReportProc_lalala
```

Help greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @xmltable TABLE (myxml XML)
INSERT INTO @xmltable 
SELECT   
'<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="SQLDS">
      <rd:DataSourceID>32e83b35-434d-4808-b685-ada14accd0e7</rd:DataSourceID>
      <DataSourceReference>SQLDS</DataSourceReference>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="SQLDS">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>SQLDS</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>ReportProc_ServerPerformanceGroup</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="GroupDetails">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>SQLDS</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>ReportProc_lalala</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>'

SELECT myxml.value('(/*:Report/*:DataSets)[1]','varchar(100)') FROM @xmltable
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Unfortunately, SQL Server.  Let me (re?)add the tag for that.

Comment: Your xml document does not match your expected output. For example `ReportProc_aaaaa` is not be be found anywhere in  your xml.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to shred yoru XML to rows and use [value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to get specific values from the XML.

```sql
select T1.N.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(128)') as DataSetName,
       T2.N.value('(*:DataSourceName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as DataSourceName,
       T2.N.value('(*:CommandType/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as CommandType,
       T2.N.value('(*:CommandText/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as CommandText
from @xmltable as T
  cross apply T.myxml.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet') as T1(N)
  cross apply T1.N.nodes('*:Query') as T2(N)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4989)

Comment: works like a charm! I figured I would need the cross apply, but couldn't figure out the colon syntax stuff.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about (untested) ....

```
select
    T.c.value(N'DataSourceName', N'nvarchar(100)') as DataSourceName,
    T.c.value(N'CommandType',N'nvarchar(100)') as CommandType,
    T.c.value(N'CommandText', N'nvarchar(100)') as CommandText
  from
    @myxml.nodes(N'/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query') T(c)
```

Comment: FWIW, that didn't work - needed singletons.  But IIRC I tried that way, and it didn't work because of the namespaces.