# How to ignore xml namespaces of root and child nodes and query the value with comma separated value from xml in SQL

Tags: sql, xml-namespaces

Here i've a xml in a table 'Test' as below

```
Id     Input
------------------------------------------------------
1      <DeviceList xmlns="www.domain.com/devicelist">
         <Device xmlns="" Name="Device1">1</Device>
         <Device xmlns="" Name="Device2">2</Device>
       </DeviceList>

2      <DeviceList xmlns="www.domain.com/devicelist">
         <Device xmlns="" Name="Device3">3</Device>
         <Device xmlns="" Name="Device4">4</Device>
       </DeviceList>

3      <DeviceList>
         <Device>4</Device>
         <Device>5</Device>
       </DeviceList>
```

my expected result would be as below,

```
Id   DeviceIds
--------------
1    1,2
2    3,4
3    4,5
```

My query,

```
SELECT Id, 
STUFF((SELECT 
', ' + CAST(Id.query('./text()') as VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM Input.nodes('/DeviceList/Device') AS Projectors(Id) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS DeviceIds
FROM test;
```

But, this query return below result,

```
Id  DeviceIds
-------------
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   4,5
```

Anybody help/suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the following question [query XML while ignoring namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332257/query-xml-while-ignoring-namespace)

It looks like /*:tagname might help.

If that does not work this question also provided another work around [Ignore XML namespace in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467387/ignore-xml-namespace-in-t-sql)

But it would require a little knowledge before of the namespace.